# Implement find and remove in Scala

Tags: scala

How is it easier to implement function that find and immutable remove the first occurrence in Scala collection:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Int)

val s = Seq(A(1,5), A(4,6), A(2,3), A(5,1), A(2,7))
val (s1, r) = s.findAndRemove(_.a == 2)
```

Result: `s1 = Seq(A(1,5), A(4,6), A(5,1), A(2,7))` , `r = Some(A(2,3))`

Comment: Are you trying to remove the first element encountered?

Comment: I updated question to make it more clear

Answer (score 4):

It finds the first element that match, and keeps order. It can be improved with List instead of Seq.

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Int)

val s = Seq(A(1,5), A(4,6), A(2,3), A(5,1), A(2,7))

val (s1, r) = s.findAndRemove(_.a == 2)


println(s1)
println(r)


implicit class SeqOps[T](s:Seq[T]) {

  def findAndRemove(f:T => Boolean):(Seq[T], Option[T]) = {

    s.foldLeft((Seq.empty[T], Option.empty[T])) {
      case ((l, None), elem) => if(f(elem)) (l, Option(elem)) else (l :+ elem, None)
      case ((l, x), elem) => (l :+ elem, x)
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, a little late to the party, but I thought I'd throw this in.

- Minimum invocations of the predicate.
- Works with most popular collection types: `Seq`, `List`, `Array`, `Vector`. Even `Set` and `Map` (but for those the collection has no order to preserve and there's no telling which element the predicate will find first). Doesn't work for `Iterator` or `String`.

-

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.language.higherKinds

implicit class CollectionOps[U, C[_]](xs :C[U]) {
  def findAndRemove(p :U=>Boolean
                   )(implicit bf :CanBuildFrom[C[U], U, C[U]]
                             ,ev :C[U] => collection.TraversableLike[U, C[U]]
                   ) :(C[U], Option[U]) = {
    val (before, after) = xs.span(!p(_))
    before ++ after.drop(1) -> after.headOption
  }
}
```

usage:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Int)
val (as, a) = Seq(A(1,5), A(4,6), A(2,3), A(5,1), A(2,7)).findAndRemove(_.a==2)
//as: Seq[A] = List(A(1,5), A(4,6), A(5,1), A(2,7))
//a: Option[A] = Some(A(2,3))

val (cs, c) = Array('g','t','e','y','b','e').findAndRemove(_<'f')
//cs: Array[Char] = Array(g, t, y, b, e)
//c: Option[Char] = Some(e)

val (ns, n) = Stream.from(9).findAndRemove(_ > 10)
//ns: Stream[Int] = Stream(9, ?)
//n: Option[Int] = Some(11)
ns.take(5).toList  //List[Int] = List(9, 10, 12, 13, 14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
def findAndRemove(as: Seq[A])(fn: A => Boolean): (Seq[A], Option[A]) = {
    val index = as.indexWhere(fn)
    if(index == -1) as -> None
    else as.patch(index, Nil, 1) -> as.lift(index)
}

val (s1, r) = findAndRemove(s)(_.a == 2)
```

Comment: Or simply `as.take(index) ++ as.drop(index+1) -> as.lift(index)`. No `index` test required.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
def findAndRemove(s:Seq[A])(p:A => Boolean):(Seq[A], Option[A])={
  val i = s.indexWhere(p)
  if(i > 0){
    val (l1, l2) = s.splitAt(i)
    (l1++l2.tail, Some(l2.head))
  }else{
    (s, None)
  }
}
```